# Embedding Youtube Video into HTML for iOS

Tags: html, ios, webview, youtube

I am loading an html file to my webview using `[self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"faq" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO]]];` Now I want to embed a youtube video into the html file. I have the file but don't know what to add in order for it to work. I have found code that let's you load it as a string but what I need is to load it inside the html file. I have tried adding, with a few fixes, the same code that I have found on other posts to the html file, but it always comes up as an external link, instead of embedded inside the html file. Here is what I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
    {
    ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId',{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})
    }
    function onPlayerReady(a)
    {
    a.target.playVideo();
    }</script>
    <iframe id="playerId" type="text/html" width="250" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9qkXs768JKY?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=1&autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And my ViewController has :

`self.webView.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = YES;
    self.webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = NO;`

Any help and guidance is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Other attempt:

I have tried the code below inside the HTML file but now it shows a play button with a line through it. Any idea how to fix it?

```
<video width="280" height="240" controls>
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
            <object data="movie.mp4" width="220" height="240">

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()
                    {
                    ytplayer=new YT.Player("playerId",{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})
                    }
                    function onPlayerReady(a)
                    {
                    a.target.playVideo();
                    }
                    </script>
                <iframe id="playerId" type="text/html" width="250" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9qkXs768JKY?enablejsapi=1&rel=0&playsinline=0&autoplay=0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                <!-- <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9qkXs768JKY" width="220" height="200">
                </embed> -->
            </object>
        </source>
    </source>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to play youtube videos in web views:

```
<iframe class="youtube-player" type="text/html" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XDJxoVIqdW0" frameborder="0">
```

Comment: Yeah I have something similar to that but it doesn't embed in the webview. It opens up in Safari.

Comment: No, I have a page with that code (only) on my site. I open it in a Web view in the app with loadRequest and the video plays in that view.

Answer (score 0):

For your UIWebView, you need to set `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to `YES` in order to show the media in your app. It defaults to `NO` on the iPhone.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIWebView/allowsInlineMediaPlayback